# How to pass multiple commands with Ansible docker_container

Tags: docker, ansible, django

We have a Django container in which, at start, we need to run two different commands:

`python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

and

`gunicorn myproj.wsgi`

We've tried all sorts of methods, but the result is always the same:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "usage: manage.py collectstatic [-h] [--noinput] [--no-post-process]
[-i PATTERN] [-n] [-c] [-l]
[--no-default-ignore] [--version]
[-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
[--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
[--no-color] [--force-color] [--skip-checks]
manage.py collectstatic: error: unrecognized arguments: gunicorn myproj.wsgi", "status": 2}
```

---

We've literally tried every solution, from `/bin/bash -c 'python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn myproj.wsgi'` to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851575/ansible-how-to-pass-multiple-commands).

The problem is: Ansible interprets the second command as arguments for the first as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679591/ansible-command-module-says-that-is-illegal-character)

The question is: how to pass two or more commands to the docker container? Is the creation of an entrypoint script the only way around?

Comment: The question you linked is answered suggest to use `shell` when you indeed need to use shell features. Are you not doing that? ([edit] your question to *show* the ansible command/task your are executing)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.

Comment: The thing is: docker_container module does not have shell as a valid parameter. So, I didn't used it. Command is what the documentation calls for, so y tried from Command to run ```/bin/bash -c 'python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn myproj.wsgi'```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup type plugins ( with_items ) along with
( community.docker.docker_container_exec ) module as below:

- name: Execute multiple commands inside foo container

  ```
  community.docker.docker_container_exec:
    container: foo
    command: /bin/bash -c "{{ item }}"
  register: result
  with_items:
    - ls -lah
    - ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
  ```

This is works with me.